# how an email is delivered can be known?

Tags: android, email

In my application I want to send an email.

I'm using AsyncTask but how can I recognize if the email is delivered so that I can stop the progressbar in postExecute method. Any help please. Here is my code. It works fine for me to send an email...

```
public class SendMainActivity extends Activity {
Button send = null;
EditText mailid = null;
String emailId = null;
ConnectivityManager conMan = null;
NetworkInfo Info = null;
ProgressBar  pro = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mailid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pro = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            Info = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            emailId = mailid.getText().toString();

            if(Info == null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no net connection ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{

                new SendEmail().execute();

            }   
        }
    });



}


class SendEmail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{

      @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
          pro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          pro.setProgress(0);
        }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {   
          GmailSender sender = new GmailSender("usermailid@gmail.com", "userpass");
          sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                  "This is Body how r u ..",   
                  "usermailid@gmail.com",   
                  emailId);   
      } catch (Exception e) {   
          Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
      } 
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pro.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put you can't recognize if your mail is delivered.

You are using GmailSender a class that can be found [here](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/android-send-email-via-gmail-actually-via-smtp/)

Now, in this class there is only a message to send mail not to check for delivery etc.

Doing that is going to be complicated. You will have to most probably write your own client from scratch.

Why don't you end the progress bar when the mail is sent?